# What are the inner text rules for for object elements in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If a control is derived from `ContentControl`, like Button, we can set Content property directly via inner text.

```
<Button> Button Text </Button>
```

But hoow does WPF knows this shall go to `Content` property and not any other?

Also what about controls that doesn't derive from `ContentControl`? The inner text is now not permitted like below. Why is that?

```
<ScrollBar> No No </ScrollBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

ContentPropertyAttribute is used.
Example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute?view=netcore-3.1

```
[ContentProperty("Title")]
public class Film
{
    public Film()
    {
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; }
    }

    private string _title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But how does WPF knows this shall go to Content property and not any other?

To indicate which property is the content of a type, there is the [`ContentProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute?view=netcore-3.1) attribute. It has a parameter for the name of the property of the control that should be used as content.

As an example, look at the definition of `ContentControl` that specifies the `Content` property.

```
[DefaultProperty("Content")]
[ContentProperty("Content")]
[Localizability(LocalizationCategory.None, Readability = Readability.Unreadable)]
public class ContentControl : Control, IAddChild
{
   //...
}
```

> The inner text is now not permitted like below. Why is that?

When you define a dependency property, you have to define its type, so the XAML preprocessor knows which type to expect. See `propertyType` parameter.

- [DependencyProperty.Register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.register?view=netcore-3.1)
- [DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerattached?view=netcore-3.1)

The conversion in XAML from a type like `string` is done with [`TypeConverters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/typeconverters-and-xaml).